# Firefox stealing mah pixels

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

http://jsfiddle.net/wzew9/

```
#menu {
    width: 1001px; height: 34px;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    background-color: #d9e4ea;  
}

#menu ul {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px 0 203px; margin: 0;
    list-style: none; line-height: normal;
}

#menu a {
    display: block; border: none;
    margin: 0 47px 0 0; padding: 5px 9px 4px 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

As you can see in the fiddle in Chrome the `menu` container's height is 34px and the `ul`'s is 30px so when I `hover` the `link` there's a 4px wide space. However, if I open it in Firefox the `ul` is 32px wide and I only get 2px space. I tried adjusting padding of every object but with no luck. So why is Firefox stealing my 2 pixels?

Comment: in FF (28) also `#menu` has 34px height... am i missing something..?

Comment: Yeah, the `#menu` is the same height, but the `ul` isn't. It's 2px bigger.

Comment: I'm seeing the ul as 1px larger in FF v28. Seems like the browser is just setting the default size differently. It would be easy enough to solve simply by explicitly setting the height of the ul as in: `#menu ul {
    height: 30px; ..etc`

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Firefox 31 nor FF 28. But if you want it to be `30px` tall, use `height: 30px`

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I needed to specify the height of every object in the `#menu` container, because otherwise different browsers just use their own size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lays in `line-height:normal`. Both web browsers have different concept of normality :).

Set line height to relative (ie. `1.2`) or absolute (ie. `20px`) value and rendering will be the same.